# Eclipse Juno says SWT not installed, but Available Software panel says it is

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Trying to do some development with SWT, but am unable too as it keeps saying the SWT package is not installed. See following screenshot

[image]

However when I go to Help->Install New Software->http://www.eclipse.org/swt/updates/3.8 it states that all items are installed for SWT Tools. Anyone ever ran inot this, and if so, what was needed to resolve?

Using Eclipse Juno with WindowBuilderPro on Windows 7. Both eclipse and Windows 7 are 64bit installs

Comment: Usually, it should work right away. Did you try [this](http://www.mkyong.com/swt/how-to-import-swt-library-into-eclipse-workspace/)?

Comment: @Baz That did the trick....wow that's quite embarrassing how bad my GoogleFu was on this issue. Please move to an answer and I shall flag as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually SWT should work right away.

However, [this](http://www.mkyong.com/swt/how-to-import-swt-library-into-eclipse-workspace/) might work.

All it does is add the SWT library to your project.